# Log: "bash: export: "PATH.": not a valid identifier" when opening terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, maven, java-home

Whenever I open a terminal, a message appear on top of it saying what I wrote in the title.
I think I messed up with the /etc/profile file when trying to get maven work.
I read some infos on exporting variables, but couldn't find my error, since I followed a guide that worked fine for other people.

The profile file I mentioned has these lines at bottom:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Setting $JAVA_HOME let me use properly Maven, but creates this annoying message. Can you help me?

Comment: Put `$`'s in front of the variables...

Comment: why assign and then export, both can be combined like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0`

Comment: Why is there a period after `PATH` in your error message? Somewhere, you have something like `export PATH.`.

Comment: Re: 123 - where should I put the &? Before EVERY variable? When I export them?
Re: piyush jaiswal - I followed a guide and it was just like that. If combining gives the same result, why bother?
Re: chepner - I know that, but I can't find it anywhere, and surely not in /profile text. Any suggestion on where or how I could find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, you are trying to export `PATH.` instead of `PATH` somewhere. You might want to check `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`files and try to find this invalid export.

The source you provided is technically ok and you don't need to add any `$` signs. Your PATH will contain `$HOME/bin` value twice though. You might want to change it to look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0
export JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: It was indeed an "export PATH." I found in the ~/.bashrc file. Solved! TY
For the last part of your answer: do I have to modify /ect/profile or another one?

Comment: You don't have to. But you have `$HOME/bin` in it twice. You can see that by typing `echo $PATH` in the terminal. I suggest you edit the `/etc/profile` as I suggested or by simply removing `:$HOME/bin` from your second line containging `PATH=`

Comment: The `export variable=value` syntax is not portable to `sh`. If you put this in a file like `.profile` which is also read by shells other than Bash, do *not* change to this syntax.